# How to cancel an UrlFetchApp.fetch after specified time?

Tags: google-apps-script, timeout

When using UrlFetchApp.fetch in a loop there are some URLs that take much longer than others and fail.

- Is there any way to cancel or break out of the loop before the fetch erros out?
- Does UrlFetchApp.fetch has a timeout parameter?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no good way to do this. We do not have a way to specify a timeout in the `UrlFetchApp` HTTP call params - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

You should log an enhancement request in the Issue Tracker with details of your use case - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: This was raised in the apps-script issue tracker in April 2014 but still hasn't been addressed:  https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3908

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem, the solution was use muteHttpExceptions.

```
var opt ={
   "validateHttpsCertificates" : false,
   "muteHttpExceptions" : true
  };
 UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
```

Comment: How could setting `muteHttpExceptions` help to cancel the `fetch()` operation after a timeout has expired?